# Matplotlib event handling and Cython

Tags: python, matplotlib, cython, typeerror, weak-references

I'm trying to connect a matplotlib event string to a function using `mpl_connect(s, func)` as in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

def onrelease(mouseEvent):
   print mouseEvent

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', onrelease)     
plt.show()
```

This runs fine in the CPython interpreter, and compiling it using a `Cython.Build.cythonize` setup file gives no problems. However, when I then try to run the actual .pyd library (using `import`), the CPython interpreter raises the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'builtin_function_or_method' object
```

Commenting out the `mpl_connect(s, func)` call and recompiling, and the thing runs fine again. So, matplotlib event handling and Cython: can it be done?

Comment: It can't be done by default. See the [docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html#weak-referencing) on how to implement it

Comment: @flebool The contents of that link should be the answer.

Comment: @tcaswell, I did not present that as an answer because it breaks the code if it is used in  "pure python mode", as the OP seems to be keeping the source as it is in a `.py` file. I don't knows if it is possible to do this without touching the original code, like [other](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html) cython directives

Comment: Then summary of the link + that last comment should be the answer.